# Avoid triethylphosphate as a side product during P-C-P coupling reaction with diethylchlorophosphate with LDA

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis, purification, organophosphorus-compounds

I have a reaction in which I perform a deprotonation of an acidic proton at a phosphate and later do a P-C-P coupling. The coupling partner is diethylchlorophosphate. Deprotonation is performed with LDA in dry THF. Deprotonation is performed at -78 Degrees Celsius and argon. Unfortunately I also observe triethylphosphate (TEP) as a side product that can not easily be separated of from the desired product by silica flash coloumn chromatography. I am wondering what the mechanism could be, how diethylchlorophosphate forms triethylphosphate and how this formation can be avoided completely? Can LDA abstract an ethanol/ ethoxy unit that subsequently reacts with diethylchlorophosphate? Than less base should have an effect? Might the slower addition of the diethylchlorophosphate to the carben ion also reduce the formation?

Comment: Does the phosphate anion generated with LDA quench normally with other electrophiles e.g. MeI?

Comment: The ion is a carbanion. I would assume that it would react with a methylation agent like you suggested. I never tried that, but I imagine an experiment were you add ethanol and diethylchlorophosphate together with a base to see if TEP is formed.

Comment: Diethyl chlorophosphate + EtOH will certainly give triethylphosphate. I'm trying to explore possible causes of the triethylphosphate production as I've done this chemistry and it worked for me. How do you quench the reaction mixture?

Comment: Reaction mixture is quenched Bei KH2PHO4. I started to observe this species only when I increased batch size. Previous runs somehow were not contaminated.

Comment: Maybe the more interesting experiment would to check if diethylchlorophosphate forms triethylphosphate just in the presence of base. In this case it would make sense to use the base im slight molar deficiency.

Comment: Worth running the experiment